# How to turn object with array into array?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to turn the values of an array inside an object to a normal array.

Right now I'm doing something like this in my AJAX success function:

```
var obj = data
              
console.log(obj)

var array = Object.keys(obj)
 .map(function(key) {
   return obj[key];
 });

console.log(array)
```

This is what I get in my console:

```
{jaar: Array(2)}
 jaar: Array(2)
  0: YEAR(Scan): "2020"
   [[Prototype]]: Object
  1: YEAR(Scan): "2021"
   [[Prototype]]: Object
  length: 2
  [[Prototype]]: Array(0)
  [[Prototype]]: Object
```

I want to have something simply as this

`["2020", "2021"]`

How can I achieve this and what am I doing wrong right now?

console.log(obj) at the start gives this output in the console:

````
jaar: Array(2)
0: {YEAR(Scan): '2020'}
1: {YEAR(Scan): '2021'}
length: 2
[[Prototype]]: Array(0)
[[Prototype]]: Object ```
````

Comment: Can you show what does your `obj` variable contain?

Comment: Have you tried `Object.values(obj.jaar)`? https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/values

Comment: Would be useful to know what you are starting with...

Comment: Hey @Justinas I've just tried what you've said. It seems to be giving me a correct array, problem now is the values inside are undefined.

Comment: Please show what console.log(obj) says at the start

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Other answer provides the must succinct code (using `.map`) - to make the the smallest change to your existing code, change:

You can read the `YEAR(Scan)` property like so:

```
return obj[key]["YEAR(Scan)"];
```

Updated code:

```js
var obj = 
  [ 
    { "YEAR(Scan)":"2020" },
    { "YEAR(Scan)":"2021" }
  ]
  

console.log(obj)

var array = Object.keys(obj)
 .map(function(key) {
   return obj[key]["YEAR(Scan)"];
 });

console.log(array)
```

Comment: I'm still getting undefined when I console.log

Comment: I don't believe YEAR(Scan) is an actual string value, it's greyed out in the console.

Comment: Hard to tell, I had to recreate the object from the console.log as it wasn't provided.   Added the `console.log(obj)` (and to the snippet above) and it looks the same to me in the browser console `0: {YEAR(Scan): '2020' }` - "year(scan)" is greyed and not in quotes.   Note, it is *not* a string, you use `["string"]` to access variables with invalid variable names `var YEAR(Scan)=2020` would give an error.   Perhaps you could add:  `console.log(JSON.stringify(obj))` so the original obj can be recreated faithfully.

Comment: {jaar: Array(2)}jaar: (2) [{…}, {…}][[Prototype]]: Object
chart.js:567 (2) [{…}, {…}]

Answer (score 1):

If you have a plain object like const `obj = { x: 10, y: 20 }` and you want to have an array of its values, you can simply use `Object.values(obj)` that will return you `[10, 20]`.

Seems like your object has more complex structure.

If you know for sure, any value of your object is a value or array, like
const `obj2 = { x: 10, y: [20, 30, 40], z: [50, 60]}` you can flatten it.

`Object.values(obj2).flat()` will return you `[10, 20, 30, 40, 50, 60]`.

For more complex structures you need to have more complex handlers.

Answer (score 1):

`jaar` is already an array of objects. You can simply use `.map()` and get the respective property value from each array element.

```
let ans =jaar.map(x => x['YEAR(Scan)']);
```